# Maker.js integration in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to integrate [Maker.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/makerjs) in an Angular Projekt. I installed it via npm:

```
npm install makerjs --save
npm install --save @types/maker.js
```

When I try to run the application I get an **Error**:

```
[…]/node_modules/makerjs/index.d.ts (3484,27): Cannot find namespace ‚opentype'.
```

Installing opentype does **not** fix the issue.

```
npm install --save opentype.js

npm install --save @types/opentype.js
```

I would be very glad if you could help me out!

Comment: How do you add maker.js to the app ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `node_modules\makerjs\index.d.ts` needs this added near the top of the file:

`/// <reference types="opentype.js" />`

It fixed the build for me. Can you try adding that to see if fixes for you as well? If so, I will make sure to add it in the next push.

Comment: There's some legacy naming around opentype and opentype.js :/